# Custom function to replace duplicates with NA does not work

Tags: r, function, if-statement, sapply

**This is my function:**

```
my_func <- function(x){
  ifelse(duplicated(x), NA_real_, first(x))
}
```

**I want to apply it to this vector:**

```
vector <- c(1,1,1,3,3,3)

[1] 1 1 1 3 3 3
```

**My expected output:**

```
[1] 1 NA NA 3 NA NA
```

**I have tried with `sapply`:**

```
sapply(vector, my_func)

gives: 
[1] 1 1 1 3 3 3

or changed the function to

my_func <- function(x){
  ifelse(duplicated(x), NA_real_, x)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
replace_dup = function(x, val = NA_real_) {
  x[duplicated(x)] = val
  x
}

replace_dup(vector)
[1]  1 NA NA  3 NA NA
```

`duplicated(x)` will be `TRUE` for the indices that you want to replace, so you can subset the vector by those indices and replace them.

I don't know why `ifelse(duplicated(x), NA_real_, x)` wasn't working for you as that is a valid solution too (although slightly more complicated). It works fine when I run it and produces the correct result.

As for `sapply()` - that would work if you had a list to which you wanted to apply this function:

```
vectors = list(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3), c(5, 5, 5))
sapply(vectors, replace_dup)

[[1]]
[1]  1 NA  2 NA  3

[[2]]
[1]  5 NA NA
```

*Edit*: As mentioned in the comments - the issue with `sapply()` here is that the function is already designed to work with an entire vector. `sapply(vector, replace_dup)` would apply `replace_dup()` to each individual element of `vector`, resulting in no duplicates identified:

```
sapply(vector, replace_dup)
[1] 1 1 1 3 3 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. `sapply` can also take vector as object, therefore I am expecting that it should work. I think the issue is with the function.

Comment: Thanks @RitchieSacramento - I was in the middle of editing my post to elaborate on this point and I think you explained it concisely. I will finish editing my post for completeness. @Tarjae - I didn't mean that `sapply()` can't take a vector as an object in general, but rather that it wouldn't make sense in this context based on @RitchieSacramento's explanation.